# Gelfand width of $l_1$ unit ball in $\infty$ metric

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

The $l_1$ balls in $l^N_p$ are well studied, but I cannot find anything about estimates of $d^m(B^N_1,l^N_\infty)$ except of
$d^m(B^N_1,l^N_\infty)\geq C\min\{1,\frac{\ln(eN/m)}{m}\}$ which is not very tight.
Can somebody point me to a source? The main reference on the subject, Carl and Stephani monograph does not help in this case either.

Comment: I think $p=1,q=\infty$ is the only case where concrete results are difficult to find. The following paper by Foucart et al may of some help in this purpose. http://www.math.drexel.edu/~foucart/gelfandreview.pdf